# auto populate a text field on a dropdown selection in a tpl file

Tags: php, html

I have a dropdown like this

```
   <div  class="constraint constraint-pattern , panel" {{#unless 
                constraints.pattern.selected}}style="display:none"{{/unless}} >
        <h3 class="full-width">{{__ "Select here"}}</h3>
        <select name="constraint" class="select2" data-has-search="false">
            <option value="[0-2]">abc</option>
            <option value="[2-4]">bcd</option>
            <option value="[4-9]">bnm</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

I want to popultate a text area when selecting a value from the dropdown.

```
    <div class="constraint constraint-pattern" {{#unless 
                constraints.pattern.selected}}style="display:none"{{/unless}}>
        <label>
            {{__ "Type"}}
        </label>

        <input type="text" readonly name="patternMask" value="abc"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is dynamic functionality and should be implemented trough javascript.

Comment: is there any way to print the selected value from the dropdown in php?

Comment: As @CasWolters said, you have to do that kind of functionality with javascript or jquery.

Comment: i have used jquery and solved :)